# configuring the interpreter for eclipse 4.6.0

Tags: eclipse, installation, pydev, interpreter

I am trying to start a new PyDev Project and first need to setup the interpreter.  The auto-config does not find a "valid interpreter".  And so I must manual config.   Perhaps someone with experience in this procedure knows of the specific name for the Interpreter Executable I am looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To get the interpreter you need to use, start the python interactive console in a shell and then do:

`import sys; print(sys.executable)`

The path printed is the interpreter you should use.

As a note, PyDev 4.6.0 is pretty old already, so, my suggestion would be upgrading to the latest release as many things were improved in the meanwhile.